# Linux merge files awk command

Tags: linux, join, awk, merge

I have two files; file 1:

```
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11044 0.9626 688423261 2 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9082 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11044 0.9926 688423263 2 01/04/2015 0.9983763000
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9144 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000
```

The second file, file 2:

```
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 1 29303546
```

The desired output:

```
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 1 29303546
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9992 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9144 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 1 29303546
```

So file 1 has many more rows than file 2. I only want to keep rows in the output that are in file 2 based on the first column, so I want `ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975` to be repeated as many times as it is in column 1 as it appears in file 2, but I don't want `ARS-BFGL-BAC-11044` in the output as it never appears in file 2.

The closest I have is the following awk command, but it won't allow `ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975` to be duplicated, i.e I only merge to the length of file 2 when my output should be a lot longer.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3;next} $1 in a {print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1 > output
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works as expected

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2 FS $3; next} $1 in a{print $0, a[$1]}' file2 file1

ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 1 29303546
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9082 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9144 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 1 29303546
```

there is no limit of how many file1 records will match to file2, but obviously file2 keys should be unique.  I'm not sure what you got when you run the same script.

If you don't mind losing the order you can use `join` and `sort`ed files

```
$ join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)

ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9082 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9144 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 1 29303546
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 1 29303546
```

with little extra juggling you can bring back the order (decorate/undecorate)

```
$ join -12 <(cat -n file1 | sort -k2) <(sort file2) | 
  sort -k2,2 | cut -d' ' -f2 --complement

ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 1 29303546
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9082 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9144 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 1 29303546
```

Comment: Ah well, now my answer looks a bit dumb ;)

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back. I was hoping to avoid join etc as I need to sort and the file will be quite big. The awk command however seems to be not joining on column 2 and 3 from file2 onto the output. It is keep the right amount of rows though. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

*Edit*: seeing the second part of karakfa's answer, I realize that the whole grep/cut circus is not required... a simple join has the same result. This is only useful if grepping reduces the size of `file1` enough such that grepping plus sorting is cheaper than sorting the whole file. `join` might also be faster if the input files are smaller.

---

If you're not limited to awk, you can use grep and core utils (requires Bash for process substitution):

```
$ join <(grep -wFf <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file2) file1 | sort) <(sort file2)
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-10975 0.9303 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 10 21225382
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9082 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11025 0.9092 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 10 84516867
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9144 688423263 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763000 1 29303546
ARS-BFGL-BAC-11193 0.9544 688423261 1 01/04/2015 0.9983763305 1 29303546
```

From the inside out:

- `cut -d ' ' -f 1 file2` extracts the first column of `file2`.
- `grep -wFf <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file2) file1 | sort` takes the extracted first column from `file2` and treats it as the file argument to grep `-f` ("match lines that match any line in this file"), and `-F` treats the lines as fixed strings instead of regexes. `-w` Makes sure we're only looking at the column as a whole, no substring matches.

  The result is piped to `sort`, because `join` requires sorted input.
- `join` then takes the result of all this, treats it as the first file, and joins with `<(sort file2)`.

Notice that the output is alphabetically sorted. If it should appear in the exact same order as in `file`, we can't use `join`.

Comment: This answer depends on `bash`, which wasn't tagged in the question. While it's a safe bet that bash exists on the OP's Linux system, and this answer provides a viable solution, you should point out that it's an *alternate* solution than the one the OP was asking for.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. The only donwfall on my side is file1 is quite large so the sort takes a while but does exactly what I want. Thank you for your help